Plotly Express choropleth giving error "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"
I am trying to use Choropleth from Plotly Express to plot data in US zip codes. I have a GeoJSON from this GitHub repo and am trying to use it in conjunction with a CSV which gives zip codes and the number of train stations in that zip code. CSV format looks like this:
zip code data frame format

My code is copied below. This results in a TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable.
The error is throwing on the fig.show() line; when I just create the figure and do not try to show it, no error is thrown.

import json
from google.colab import files
import pprint
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

nj_geo_data = files.upload()
## Using files.upload, select the appropriate GeoJSON file

train_df = pd.read_csv("Train Data.csv", converters={'zipcodes': str})

fig = px.choropleth(train_df, geojson = nj_geo_data, 
                     locations='Train Station?', 
                     featureidkey = 'properties.ZCTA5CE10', 
                     projection='mercator')

fig.show()


CSV format should be actual text from CSV file not an image.

I will comment on my guess. The size of this zip code data is very large. I have not checked all the contents, but it is possible that the geomerty data is not correct. I tried to draw only Nevada with the original data as the referenced author commented and it was drawn correctly I have expanded it to Colab, please refer to it.

The CSV format is copied below; I am taking a sample to avoid uploading the full, large file.
zipcodes,Train Station?
08854,0
08873,0
10588,0
11581,0
07008,0
07063,0
08820,0
19026,0
11557,0
07001,0

If the zip code data is too large, is there another source for a manageable geoJSON file with US zip codes? If it is divided by state or some other division that would work well!

I used this geojson to solve your issue. Why don't you try this?

In case anyone else stumbles across this looking for a solution - I figured out what I was doing wrong. The way I was loading my geojson file (Google Collab's files.upload) messed with the file format. Using json.load instead gets an appropriately interpreted geoJSON file which works appropriately. Thank you to everyone for your help!
